# How to notify customers an Android app will stop working after upgrading to Android 8

Tags: android

I am a mobile application tester who works in the R&D area of the premium German car company.

How would you deal with the situation where your app stops working on the primary target device after upgrading to Android 8 because the hardware used in the car does not support the new Bluetooth stack changes in Android 8?

The new hardware for the car will take a month or two to get released; so until then how can we support our existing customers - any thoughts?

Workarounds tried so far:

1. Contacted device manufacturer but have been told that there is no possible solution from handset side
2. Push notifications for customers to notify about the issue - we need to do a major app release and it’s not wise to do with the current budgeting needs
3. Our customer assistance policies does not support to reply back directly on the store reviews
4. We cannot stop users from upgrading their device because some of their apps might need the new OS for security reasons.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue for your project managers and business analysts. Is this a hypothetical question or have you been tasked with finding the solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about testing. This could potentially be asked on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ if the question is primarily about how best to communicate/notify users effectively.

Comment: Sure, I will take this in the right forum. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: @theonlydanever - Yes I am tasked with finding the solution. Since Android 8 rolled out in India bit latter than in Germany, we could not capture it in our regular testing phases.